# Equivalent to git merge origin/master in libgit2

Tags: git, libgit2

I am using libgit2 C Version 0.20.0 library. I have successfully implement git_remote_fetch() which update oid but after that I am not able to call merge method properly.

Tried to call int git_merge(git_repository *repo, const git_annotated_commit **their_heads, size_t their_heads_len, const git_merge_options *merge_opts, const git_checkout_options *checkout_opts); But second parameter git_annotated_commit should be constant. I am getting git_annotated_commit **out from method git_annotated_commit_lookup() method. could anybody tell me how I can convert git_annotated_commit **out as const ? Is there any other method to get git_annotated_commit **out as constant ?

Using Git bash console I execute command **git merge origin/master** which update content of repository successfully, could any body tell me which command I need to use in libgit2 to do same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert the `git_annotated_commit **out` to `const git_annotated_commit **their_heads` you should use: `const_cast`, like:

```
const git_annotated_commit **their_heads = const_cast<const git_annotated_commit**>(out);
```

Comment: could you please suggest me using which method of libgit2 library I can perform **git add . , git commit and git push** ?

Comment: @Monty Glad that it worked :). You should be able to find all the suggested methods here: https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/.